# What is the meaning of "G4M" when it comes to chargers?

Tags: samsung, charging

What does "G4M" mean in "[30W Quick Home Charger w Type-C 10ft USB Cable G4M for LG V35 ThinQ, Q7 Plus, G Pad X II 10.1, V50 ThinQ 5G, Stylo 4 Plus, Google Nexus 5X, G8 ThinQ, G7 ThinQ, 5 - Microsoft Surface Go (10")](https://www.walmart.com/ip/30W-Quick-Home-Charger-w-Type-C-10ft-USB-Cable-G4M-LG-V35-ThinQ-Q7-Plus-G-Pad-X-II-10-1-V50-ThinQ-5G-Stylo-4-Google-Nexus-5X-G8-G7-5-Microsoft-Surfac/624795466)"? I asked the question because I am thinking of buying "[Cargador Fast Charge G4M Samsung (25W - Type C - Blanco)](https://www.worten.es/productos/cargador-fast-charge-g4m-samsung-25w-type-c-blanco-mrkean-7427269108262?gclid=Cj0KCQjw3JanBhCPARIsAJpXTx4RyR2Ph-0SyeQNLfy0DP1wPZRdb_axJPjjsqnr2QsKlhyJHLhTaQcaAt-bEALw_wcB)". The first link is the only English site that I could find that contains "G4M". Thank you!

Comment: Regardless of the markings, I always ask the seller if it will work with my phone, brand and model. I  would guess that G4 is 4th generation. But the way Usb has evolved, nothing is certain.

Comment: I can't find any reference or standard for "G4M" from any OEM or "reputable" manufacturer... Could simply be a generic part number or model number from a Chinese manufacturer or something similar, or a mistranslation of something.

Comment: Since the results are mostly in Spanish, I have a feeling that this is something specific to Spain, perhaps some kind of certification?